# There is very much space before and after the condition of the equation

Tags: equations

I do not understand the code here. Where can I change the space options? Also the right side of the condition, I am not able to add "space" between text.

```
\documentclass[
    pdftex,
    12pt,
    a4paper,
    chapterprefix,
    headinclude,
    %headsepline,
    %footsepline,
    colordvi,
    twoside,
    parskip=half,
    final,
    appendixprefix,
    pointlessnumbers,
    tablecaptionabove,
    %emulatestandardclasses,
    BCOR=12mm,
    DIV=16, 
    bibliography=totocnumbered,
    listof=totocnumbered,
    %listof=totoc,
    listof=entryprefix,
    toc=sectionentrywithdots]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}     % place the subscripts and superscripts in the right position
\usepackage{amsfonts}               % additional fonts like \mathbb, \mathfrak
\usepackage{amssymb}                % additional symbols



\newenvironment{conditions}
  {\par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\noindent
   \tabularx{\columnwidth}{>{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}}
  {\endtabularx\par\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}}

\begin{document}

\section{Forced vibration of Single Degree of Freedom System with damping}
The complementary solution of equation is the free vibration response given by
\begin{equation}
    u_{c}(t) = e^{−\zeta\omega_{n} t} \left(A cos \omega_{D}t + B sin\omega_{D} t\right)
\end{equation}

\begin{align*}
\text{where:}\quad 
m &= mass\\
k &= stiffness\\
c &= damping coefficient\\
\zeta &= damping ratio\\
u &= displacement\\
\dot{u} &= velocity\\
\ddot{u} &= acceleration\\
\omega_{D} &= \omega_{n}\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}\\
A &= u_{0}\\
B &= \frac{\dot{u_{0}} + \zeta\omega_{n} u_{0}}{\omega_{D}}\\
\end{align*}

\subsection{Forced vibration of Single Degree of Freedom }





\end{document}
```

code is responding to me as,

```
     where: c = dampingcoefficient
            ζ = dampingratio
```

Comment: As always on this site: if you want help provide a full but minimal example that (1) shows your problem, and (2) others can copy to replicate it without having to add anything. Here we know nothing about your preamble, document class etc. So sorry as it sits here, we cannot help.

Comment: Is it possible now to understand?

Comment: What is that `conditions` env used for? You don't use it in this MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably just do this:

(I cleaned a lot that are not necessary for this MWE, not you had a UTF8 char as a minus instead of an ascii hyphen)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}     % place the subscripts and superscripts in the right position
\usepackage{amssymb}                % additional symbols

\begin{document}

\section{Forced vibration of Single Degree of Freedom System with damping}
The complementary solution of equation is the free vibration response given by
\begin{align}
  u_{c}(t) &= e^{-\zeta\omega_{n} t} (A \cos \omega_{D}t + B
  \sin\omega_{D} t)
  \\
  \nonumber
  \begin{split}
    \text{where:}\quad 
    m &= \text{mass}\\
    k &= \text{stiffness}\\
    c &= \text{damping coefficient}\\
    \zeta &= \text{damping ratio}\\
    u &= \text{displacement}\\
    \dot{u} &= \text{velocity}\\
    \ddot{u} &= \text{acceleration}\\
    \omega_{D} &= \omega_{n}\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}\\
    A &= u_{0}\\
    B &= \frac{\dot{u_{0}} + \zeta\omega_{n} u_{0}}{\omega_{D}}
  \end{split}
\end{align}

\subsection{Forced vibration of Single Degree of Freedom }





\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I need the equation environment. To label it. and below the equation, I am writing the explanation of the terms.

Comment: Why? This does exactly the same. You evan even use gather and remove the & from the first equation, then they have no common alignment. This does exactly the same as you posted above. The extra spaces you get is from ending and starting envs, plus the blank line you left in the code.

Comment: ok. perfect. and can I also use the label? to reference the equation?

Comment: Of course, may I suggest you study the math envs that come with the `amsmath` package,. Note my use of `\nonumber` before the `split` env. Split would get a simple eq number, but we remove it with `\nonumber`